# Count or Select in Entity Framework, Optimal solution

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have to display a number regarding to new messages from database.

Which solution is optimal?

1) Create a trigger in database that will increment an countValue in database and select this 'countValue' from Entity framework.

2) Count directly from entity framework the number (databaseContext.MyTable.Count();) .

Thanks

Comment: Have you try something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database keeps track on the tables' row counts, so you dont't need to do that by yourself.

EF's `.Count()` will call SQL's `COUNT()` method which in turn will return your result in no time.

Comment: I need to do this for an notification action so I will call the getNewNotificationsCount method very often.

Comment: I can create a table with userId and notifications number (with an trigger that will update notifications nr ) and select only a row in order to get the result or just count rows from EF when I need. I want to know the optimal solution for this.